# Function That Uncheck All Checkboxes When One Of Them Is Checked(Selected By Class)

Tags: javascript

I want to uncheck all other checkboxes aside from the checked one.
I tried this function but it doesn't work properly.

```
let wordch = document.getElementsByClassName('checkboxes');
function uncheck(){
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
        if(wordch[i].checked != false){
            if (i - 1 > 0 && i + 1 < wordch.length) {
                wordch[i - 1].checked = false;
                wordch[i + 1].checked = false;    
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the easiest solution for your problem would be to replace your checkbox elements with radio buttons, as they have the required behaviour built-in.

Comment: you are using the "checked" property to check if the checkbox is selected or not. but, this property only returns true or false and does not allow you to set the value. To set the value, you need to use the "checked" attribute. also you only need to check the checkbox that is clicked instead of looping thorugh all

Comment: @AfzalK. ["The `checked` IDL attribute allows scripts to manipulate the _checkedness_ of an `input` element. ... on setting, it must set the element's _checkedness_ to the new value ... ."](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#dom-input-checked) You **can** set the checkedness of an `input` element via the `checked` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the best solution would involve radio buttons instead of checkboxes. But if you insist on using checkboxes, then the following could be one way to go:

```js
const cbs=document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes");
cbs.forEach(cb=>cb.onclick=ev=>cbs.forEach(c=>c!==cb&&(c.checked=false)));
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="6"> 6<br>
```

The collection `cbs` contains all checkboxes of the given class `.checkboxes`. A `.forEach()` loop over this collection assigns the `.onclick` event handler to each individual checkbox. Within the event handler the `.checked` state of each of the `cbs` collection's elements `c` is set to either `false`, if the current checkbox `c` in that loop is not identical to the clicked one (`cb`) or to the clicked value if they *are* identical.

Here is another version of the script. It is basically the same but hopefully a little bit easier for you to understand:

```js
const cbs=document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes"); // collection of all checkboxes
cbs.forEach(cb=>{ // assign an event handler for "click" to each checkbox cb:
  cb.addEventListener("click",()=>{ // this is the click event handler function
    // each time this click event handler is triggered
    // go over each checkbox again and ...
    cbs.forEach(c=>{ 
       // ... change only the "checked" attribute for those c elements 
       // that or not identical to the clicked one (cb)
       if (c!==cb) c.checked=false;
    }); // end of inner forEach
  }); // end of event handler function
}); // end of outer forEach
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="6"> 6<br>
```

And last but not least, here is another solution based on radio buttons instead of checkboxes:

```js
const cbs=document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes");
cbs.forEach(cb=>cb.onclick=()=>{cb.checked=(cb.check=!cb.check)});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="rb1" class="checkboxes" value="1"> 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1"class="checkboxes" value="2"> 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" class="checkboxes" value="3"> 3<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" class="checkboxes" value="4"> 4<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" class="checkboxes" value="5"> 5<br>
<input type="radio" name="rb1" class="checkboxes" value="6"> 6<br>
```

The script is still necessary in order to uncheck a radio button by clicking on it again. The onclick event handler for the radio buttons sets the `.checked` attribute  to the negated value of a new `.check` property that is then reassigned to that same `cb` object. `cb` is the loop variable  inside the `.forEach()` loop and contains a reference to the radio button. Its `check` property is therefore *not* an attribute of the actual radio button DOM element but merely a property of the `cb` object which is one of the six elements inside the initially created `cbs` collection.

Comment: Great but the problem here is that I can't uncheck the checkbox after it's checked.

Comment: Ok, that problem is fixed. Please try again.

Comment: Perfect, I'm trying to understand your code but it's too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

assigning a single event listener to a parent element and using event bubbling to handle events for multiple child elements.

```js
let checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxes");

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener("change", function() {
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      if (checkbox != this) {
        checkbox.checked = false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.checkboxes {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes">
```